# In Excel how do I create a sum that would assign a value to five different Strings

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a survey populated in excel with a slider scale.

Currently, columns will have responses of the following:

- Strongly Agree
- Agree
- Neutral
- Disagree
- Strongly Disagree

How do I create a total sum of each column that will:

- Match each cell to a value based on the response. I.e. Strongly agree would equal 5, Agree would Equal 4, Neutral would Equal 3, Disagree would equal 2 and Strongly Disagree would equal 1.
- Then add these all up into a total.

I.e. you had these cells:

Agree
Agree
Neutral
Disagree

The total would be 4 + 4 + 3 + 2 which is 13.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it in one, you can use this array formula, so confirm with Ctrl, Shift and Enter.

```
=SUM(CHOOSE(MATCH(D8:D11,$D$1:$D$5,0),5,4,3,2,1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Setup a "Hidden" tab or table that assigns a Value to the String.

```
=if(A1:A100="strongly Disagree";1;ifA1:A100="Disagree";2;If(A1:A100="Neutral";3;If(A1:A100="Agree;4;If(A1:A100="Strongly Agree";5;" ")))))
```

Put that in as many cells as questions (you could even number them so you can find the question with the value again. 
Then in the cell you want the total value to pop up put a =Sum({cell range})

Would that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Create a lookup table somewhere and then use a VLOOKUP to get the value of a response. See screenshot below. Please note the formula.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have excel 2016 you can use the switch statement. Assuming the rating is in cell A1:

```
=SWITCH(LOWER(A1),”strongly agree”,5,”agree”,4,”neutral”,3,”disagree”,2,”strongly disagree”)
```